# How to check the on click event properly?

Tags: jquery, html

I have written two functions to control the on click event

**jQuery**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<title>Classic Online Store</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login-form.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/nav-menus.css"/>
<!--tabs in the accordion -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/acard.css"/>

<!--  the template script-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- side category accordion -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/custom.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/customlog.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="sideacardeion/script.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$('#btn_Run').click(function(e) {
        alert("Hello! ShareChiWai.");

});
</script>

</head>
```

**HTML**

I have menus running here

.....

Then  the login form

```
<?php 

if ($_SESSION['Id'] > 0 ){

echo '<h1>Login Form</h1>

       <h2>You have loged in already<br/></h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Click logout to exit </h3>
       <br />
       <h3><a href="logout.php"> logout</a></h3>';


 } else {
 echo  '  <h1>Login Form</h1>

<div id="contact_form">  
 <form name="contact" action="">  
 <fieldset>        
    <label for="email" id="email_label"><font color="#FFFFFF">Email</font></label>  
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label>  

    <label for="phone" id="phone_label"><font color="#FFFFFF">Password</font></label>  
    <input type="password" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="phone" id="phone_error">This field is required.</label>  
   <input type="button" id="btn_Run" value="Run" />      

    <br />  
    </fieldset>  
    </form>  
 </div>  

';

if (isset($_SESSION['attmpt'])){
    $leftlog = $_SESSION['attmpt'] - 4;
    echo '<div class="atmpt" id="atmpt"><font color="#FF0000"> You have '.$leftlog.' more chanse(s)</font></div>';

    }
   }

  ?>
```

the rest of the page

this one does nothing,

I don't know what is wrong with my click event function? Could you tell me how to check the click event properly? I have Googled all the jQuery event controller, and I found that my first function is supposed to be working fine, but it doesn't.

I get no error, and no alert in console when I click on the login btn

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you included `jQuery`?

Comment: The second example may work, but it's bad practice. Please read some of these results: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

Comment: Do you have both of those buttons on the page at the same time?

Comment: @ArunPJohny How's that relates ?  http://jsbin.com/egErizOG/2/edit

Comment: Is the button `#btn_Run` added to the DOM after page load? In that case the when the click handler is being applied, the button is not present and hence the handler does not respond to the click event.

Comment: its working.. http://fiddle.jshell.net/Grp2Q/7/

Comment: @RGraham I bet it's an id issue.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I thought jQuery version was working :(

Comment: What is the output of `alert($("#btn_Run").length)` ?

Comment: @RGraham I was talking about the case of button being added dynamically to the DOM after `document.ready` has completed.

Comment: Without more of your source code, or an example demo of what you are working with (via jsfiddle) it is just guess work as to what the problem may be. Update your question with more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz make sure that jQuery file is loaded when you running code.

You can do this by:

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery library loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery library is not loaded
}
```

For safe side you may try to reload jQuery if not loaded:

```
if (!window.jQuery || typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
  // create script Element and append in head of HTML
  var jqElement = document.createElement('script'); 
  jqElement.type = 'text/javascript';
  // Path to jquery.js file, eg. Google hosted version
  jqElement.src = '/path-to-your/jquery.min.js'; //or reference an alternate CDN link
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqElement);
}
```

Comment: In the second code you're missing : async , appending to script location. ( not every html has head) , you can remove the second part of ||

Comment: with modern browsers, it doesn't matter whether you set script.async = true or not, it will be executed asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

Is your button created after the page load. Anyways, Try this, and let me know what happens:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click','#btn_Run',function(){
        alert("Hello! ShareChiWai.");
    });
});
</script>
```

Instead of `'body'`. Instead we can use any selector which is present right from the page load.

Comment: So this is supposed to delegate the event? right? It doesn't.

Comment: @skshoyeb previous version of click function. Time to update your knowledge.

Comment: @BlackSheep : oops got it., i guess the new edit does the delegation if i m not wrong. You could enlighten me if I m wrong though :)

Comment: @skshoyeb I have changed it but no luck yet, it's weird

Comment: hm, Is it possible for you to share entire code..! @user3150692

Comment: I have tried to be as specific as possible, I have edited my questions, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the error, by changing the function to

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#btn_Run').click(function(e) {
        alert("Hello! ShareChiWai.");

});
});
```

thanks for all your help and try, really appreciated. :)